# Get key of javascript object forEach

Tags: javascript, object, foreach, key, taffydb

I am using Taffy DB, and have a search feature which searches for a property:

```
var finded = properties({type:"small"}).get();

finded.forEach( function() {
    var name = this['name'];
    alert('The matched result is ' + name + '.');
});
```

The the first returns two javascript objects, for both properties found.

The next section of code (line 3-) is supposed to perform a function on each object retrieved to get its 'Name' key and then post it in an alert box.

However, instead it just comes out blank. There isn't `[object Object]`, there isn't `undefined` it's just blank (with the exception of the quoted text, of course.)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `this` in `forEach` is not refer to an array. If you don't provide second argument callback function will be executed in global context.

Comment: @Givi How can I work around this then?

Comment: If you iterate over array of object you can use `finded.forEach( function(value) { var name = value.name; });`

Comment: It works, WOW thank you so much :) Post this as an answer so I can accept it. Fantastic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is not refer to an array or to the element of that array, instead if you don't provide second argument of [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), callback function will be executed in global context.

```
finded.forEach(function (value) {
    var name = value.name;
});
```